# Why jar file doesn't work and thows exception?

Tags: java, maven, telegram-bot

Error: Unable to initialize main class com.telegram.client.MyClasses.Main
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/telegram/telegrambots/generics/LongPollingBot
I do maven install, then run jar file, installation have some warnings, but not errors. So when i run jar file it throws this alert. I dont use this class in my project and i cant understand why it doesnt work.
P.S Sorry for mistakes, I just learn English at school.
My pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>TradingBot2</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <okhttp3.version>3.12.1</okhttp3.version>
        <fastjson.version>1.2.47</fastjson.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
            <artifactId>okhttp</artifactId>
            <version>${okhttp3.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.alibaba</groupId>
            <artifactId>fastjson</artifactId>
            <version>${fastjson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.4</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.4</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.telegram</groupId>
            <artifactId>telegrambots</artifactId>
            <version>3.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.telegram</groupId>
            <artifactId>telegrambots-meta</artifactId>
            <version>3.5</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>


    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                    <compilerArgument>-Xlint:unchecked</compilerArgument>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>com.binance.client.MyClasses.Main</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: It is most likely that when you exported the jar file, you didn't export dependencies with it. Make sure to add the dependencies when you export it, otherwise, it won't find the classes.

Comment: excuse me, can you explain how can i do it?

Comment: What IDE are you using for Java?

Answer (score 0):

This is how we can use external jars into maven project -

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.example.helloworld</groupId>
    <artifactId>example-app</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <scope>system</scope>
    <systemPath>${basedir}/lib/yourJar.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

Original Code-
https://intellipaat.com/community/6786/how-to-add-local-jar-files-to-a-maven-project

Comment: it could help me if it was problem with local libraries, but this class (LongPoolingBot) is in maven libraries.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question

Answer (score 0):

have a look at https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.telegram/telegrambots ,you need to include the dependency in your `pom.xml` like this :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.telegram</groupId>
    <artifactId>telegrambots</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: yes but your telegram dependency-version is **very** old, you should probably think about updating it because i dont actually know if old versions include the classes&methods you are referecing in your code. Also : using PowerMockito is a slight hint at a faulty test design, you shouldn't be forced to modify static classes and such

Comment: i have cut out peace of code, where this dependency had been used, and it has thrown same problem with other library classes.  I think it dont use this library in jar, and i dont know why

Comment: with commands like `mvn dependency:tree` you can view all of your dependencies and look for the one which is including the telegram bot. After that, you could try and remove it if you dont need it. In general, you always should remove everything which isnt actually necessary for your project